# COLLECTION_MAP_REFRESH_IN_PROGRESS reason with RequestCancelledException while connecting to couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

I am a newbie to couchbase. In one of my applications, we are occassionally getting
`com.couchbase.client.core.error.RequestCancelledException` with `NO_MORE_TRIES (COLLECTION_MAP_REFRESH_IN_PROFRESS)` reason.

I tried searching about this reason, but could find any relevant doc which explains this reason in detail. Can someone help?

[Edit:]
My erroneous code looks like below, and error is triggered on second line (document fetch step).

I have a hunch that the `Collection collection = ...` is an async step and the collection isn't fully populated by the time the `collection.get(id)` is invoked.

```
 Collection collection = scope.collection(myCollection);
 MyEntity myEntity = collection.get(id).contentAs(MyEntity.class);
```

I will paste the couchbase version once I have that info, but rest assured it's quite a newer version.

[Edit:]
My couchbase version is 7.1.3 EE. and Couchbase client SDK 3.2.4

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using? Also, is this related to Spring Data? If so, perhaps paste the relevant portion of the code.

Comment: Added details, as requested. Thanks.

Comment: I see you removed the Spring tag, but this is the Java SDK, correct?

Comment: That's right. It's the Java SDK.

Comment: I think your hunch might be correct. What is your KV timeout set to? If you search your app log for CoreCreatedEvent you should see the timeout settings as part of the "timeoutConfig" object. This message is logged at INFO level to the "com.couchbase.core" category.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Step 2 to execute only once step 1 is finished executing?

Comment: @YoYoMoneySingh Couchbase SDK engineer here, and looks to me like the SDK hasn't finished bootstrapping yet.  We occasionally see this in higher latency setups.  As David says, you could increase the KV timeout. You can also apply the "wan-development" environment profile, which will do the same.  Or - my preferred option - you could add a cluster.waitUntilReady() during initialisation, which will block until bootstrapping is complete.